# Magento 2.3.1 minicart.phtml translations

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, translate

I'm trying to translate the string **items** from
`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml` without success.

I have a dictionary already created in `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/i18n/es_ES.csv` and I tried collecting all the strings using:

`php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases --output="app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/i18n/es_ES.csv"`

The .csv file doesn't collect the string for the translation. What am I missing?

[image: minicart.phtml]

Comment: Please check https://mobecls.com/working-mini-cart-magento-2/

Comment: what part you are trying to translate?

Comment: In the image above **items** string in line 27 @oscprofessionals

Comment: Are you trying to change item names. Item names are coming from data base and product admin interface data and not controlled by translation csv file.If we missed something please do elaborate further so that we can comment.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find the correct way to translate strings from `pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/es_ES/js-translation.json` so I decided to try the inline translation tool and it works like a charm. Hope I can save time and effor to some.